# Eclipse in Ubuntu keeps recreating the .classpath and ignores previous save

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have two Android projects, AndroidLib and AndroidApp.  AndroidApp is dependent on AndroidLib.  The AndroidLib project uses some libraries which I do not want to export therefore I have unchecked them from "Order and Export" tab in Java Build Path. I then close Eclipse and confirm that the .classpath under AndroidLib does not exported="true" for those libraries.  However when I launch Eclipse again it addes exported="true" for all libraries.

Does anyone know how can I stop Eclipse from adding exportd="true" automatically?

I am running Eclipse Kepler on Ubuntu.  I do not see the same behavior with Eclipse on Windows.

Comment: Are you by any change using a code repository like Git or SVN? If so, it may be responsible.

Comment: I am using Mercurial.  So is it trying to update from Mercurial everytime I open eclipse?  that does not happen in Windows.  How do I make these changes permanent.

Comment: I'm sorry @anirus, I do not know anything about Mercurial to answer your question.

Comment: I also tried removing Mercurial, same result.

Comment: Hi, [I did some research](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-build-path.htm), and you can edit the "exported" attribute of a classpath entry by right clicking your project > **Build Path** > **Configure Build Path...** and going to the "**Order and Export**" tab. I think any check marked entries there will be marked as "exported".

Comment: I have tried this.  However after I close and reopen eclipse they are automatically checked back.  I think there is a bug with how eclipse works in Ubuntu(?)